# "adverb + adjective " vs "adjective +adverb "

Tags: grammar

> **1)** It was well planned /thought out.
>
> **2)** It was Planned /thought out well.

Off and On I see the number (1) sentences. My question is, Is the number (2) correct with same meaning?  If not, then why?

Comment: Of your four permutations, only *It was well planned* is idiomatically natural (*It was planned well* is "valid", but relatively unlikely compared to the former). The valid version using ***thought*** is [*It was well **thought out***](https://www.google.com/#tbm=bks&q=%22was+well+thought+out%22)

Comment: This isn't a matter of "grammar" - it's just a matter of which forms are idiomatically established (and therefore *preferred, more likely*). An easy way to get a feel for native speaker preference is to compare 34,000 hits for [was well planned](https://www.google.com/#tbm=bks&q=%22was+well+planned%22) against just 2730 for [was planned well](https://www.google.com/#tbm=bks&q=%22was+planned+well%22) (and note that many of the latter will be ***...well in advance, well over a year ago,*** etc., so it's even less common than the bare figures might suggest).

Answer (score 1):

- Construction 1

It was [AdjP].

This adjective phrase was constructed using the past-participle form of the verb and headed by a modifier - an adverb here.

*well planned* => AdjP

> It was [well planned].

- Construction 2

It was Past-Participle_form_of_verb + adverb.

This adverb says how the action/process took place.

> It was [planned] [well].

---

> It was well planned.
>
> It was planned well.

Both of them have the same meaning. Neither is more correct than the other.